# How do these 'reverse' and 'twist' functions work in Ruby? (functional programming)

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, reverse, reduce

I redefined function `fold` using `reduce` method in Ruby.

```
def fold(f, init, lst)
    lst.reduce(init){|w, a| f.call(w, a)}
end
```

I have `reverse` and `twist` functions below and examples on how they should work.

```
reverse ‘(a b (c d) e)) --> (e (c d) b a)

def reverse(lst)
    fold(lambda{|w, a| [a] + w}, [] of Any, lst)
end
```

How is it possible to reverse an array with only `[a] + w`??
and what does `[] of Any` mean?

```
twist ‘(a b (c d) e)) --> (e (d c) b a)

def twist(lst)
    fold(lambda{|w, a| ([a.kind_of?(Array) ? twist(a) : a]) + w}, [], lst)
end
```

For `twist` function, I know it means that "if an element `a` is in the `Array`, it returns `twist(a)`, and it it's not in the `Array`, it returns just `a`". But I don't get how this algorithm works..

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].reduce([]) { |w, a| [a] + w }` might be easier to analyze. It also reverses the array but without all that indirection.

Comment: @Stefan But how does 'adding' ([a]+w) make it reverse? I don't get the algorithm

Comment: @Stefan ohhh is it just keep adding each element to the very 'beginning' of the array?

Comment: It's `[1] + []` → `[2] + [1]` → `[3] + [2, 1]` → `[4] + [3, 2, 1]` etc. The left-hand side is the current element wrapped in `[...]` and the right-hand side is the block's previous result. You could also write `reduce([]) { |w, a| w.unshift(a) }` which would re-use the initial `[]` instead of creating new arrays on each iteration.

Comment: @Stefan wow I understood right away... thxx so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible to reverse an array with only `[a] + w`??
> and what does `[] of Any` mean?

`[] of Any` is not legal Ruby syntax, it is a `SyntaxError`. Since the code is not even legal syntax, i.e. it cannot even be parsed, it makes no sense to analyze how it runs, because it *can't run at all*.

> For `twist` function, I know it means that "if an element `a` is in the `Array`,

No, it means "if the element `a` *is* an `Array` (or more precisely, is a *kind of* `Array`)

> it returns `twist(a)`,

No, it returns `[twist(a)] + w`

> and it it's not in the `Array`,

No, again, it means "if `a` *is not* an `Array`.

> it returns just `a`".

No, it returns `[a] + w`.

> But I don't get how this algorithm works..

`a` is the current element, `w` is the result that we have built up so far. If `a` is a simple element (not an `Array`), we return `[a] + w`, in other words, we move `a` to the beginning.

If `a` is an `Array`, we call `twist` on it first, *then* move it to the beginning.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistakes! I didn't know that it moves to the 'beginning'...
it helped a lot☺️☺️